# How to get Data for Location App?

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps

I am planning to build an app that would find the shortest distance from one location to another and other things too.

It requires the latitudes and longitudes of a place and distance of all the coordinates from say X meters from it, distance in the sense of actual road distance. I do not want any graphics or showing the map but just the plain data.

This means that i can query for some address with the distance X, and it would give me the details. I looked into Google Map Api, but that looks like to cater for some kind of client job scheduling. I even looked into Bing Map Api. It seemed to provide things. But i thought to ask here before proceeding.

Any tips on available options ?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you should be able to find many many code samples out there for models. But first:

I'm not sure what you mean by Google Maps API looks like it caters to client job scheduling; it actually is pretty much the opposite!  There are limitations to how many requests per day can come from one IP.  Also, the licensing for Google Maps is made for client facing applications like web based Store Locators (the application that I used it for) and often requires you to display a Google Map with the information.

You do have a limited license to do business related geocoding and searches.

I think you may be more interested in a product like Microsoft MapPoint http://www.microsoft.com/mappoint/en-us/home.aspx

While there are many competing products and services, the price point here is ***great***.  You may also be able to get it for free along with other apps if you register for their BizSpark program http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx

HTH

Geezer